# Does TCP/IP port:2382 for SSAS 2017 support encryption in data transit?

Tags: encryption, tcp, ssas-tabular

I am working on a requirement which is based on the below article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0

Here in this configuration the web layer connects to the SSAS instance via the TCP/IP port : 2382.

Can anyone help me to know whether the TCP/IP port: 2832 supports encryption while data in transit?

Comment: Yes.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jason_howell/2013/02/26/how-do-i-ensure-analysis-services-client-tcp-connectivity-is-encrypted/

Comment: Thanks David for your response. I did analysis and found the same article.